# how to detect if scroll is below specific view in scrollview react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to hide the absolute positioned button when scroll indicator is below a specific view in scrollview. any help would be appreciated. I tried using onscroll method and other inview plugin combination but I'm not getting the desired result. any help would be appreciated.

```
 <ScrollView  style={{ width: deviceDimesions.width, alignSelf: 'center' }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true} bounces={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
<View>View 1</View>
<View>View 2</View>
<View>View 3. (hide buttons when scroll reached at this view)</View>
<View>View 4</View>
</ScrollView>

{this.state.user && <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 10, backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 15, width: deviceDimesions.width, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
<View>}
```

Answer (score -1):

For this, i suggest to use `IntersectionObserver` API. It was solved here: [Detect whether element is above or below the viewport on intersect leave with intersection observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980851/detect-whether-element-is-above-or-below-the-viewport-on-intersect-leave-with-in)

Comment: `IntersectionObserver` is not available in React Native.